# Regex help to match number pattern in a URL

Tags: regex

I am updating a website and need to forward url's with a specific pattern to a new page. I need to identify those URL's using a regex so only those get redirected.

An example of the URL I need to match on is;

**/events/2894/an-event-page-title-123**

I would not want to match on this URL

**/events/example-page-123**

The way to positively identify the URL's is to check for '/events/' followed by only numbers in the next section of the URL. there may be more or less than 4 numbers, but only ever numbers. As in the example, there is also

```
/^events\/([0-9]+)\/([a-z0-9_\.-]+)$/
```

Above is what I have tried which is probably very wrong as I am not very experienced with Regex (please stifle any laughter), but this is probably straightforward for someone.. many thanks in advance

Comment: Your regex looks fine now. In what language/tool are you doing this?

Comment: @anubhava I'm entering the regex into a php redirection wordpress plugin if that helps

Comment: ok then `^\/events\/([0-9]+)\/[\w.-]+$` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^\/events\/([0-9]+)\/([a-z0-9_\.-]+)
```

Try this.See demo.Your regex was not matching because `\` before `events was not matched.

http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/45

Comment: Thanks, this worked straight away and was the most useful answer - thanks also for putting me onto regex101.com which looks useful for future issues

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

`\/events\/\d+\/`

which is `/events/` followed by 1 or more digits, followed by `/`

Comment: I like the brevity but it didn't immediately work when I tried it I'm afraid - definitely useful for someone else though I'm sure